# Copying data from every 8th sheet without referencing them "manually"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 80 worksheets.

I want to copy two columns from Sheet1 to the next 7 Sheets (Sheet2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7, 8) 
and then from Sheet9 to the next 7 sheets (Sheet10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 , 16) 
and then from Sheet 17 to the next 7 sheets and so on...

I have no idea how to loop this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please include the code you are working on in your question.

Comment: If your sheets are in chronological order (left to right) to can loop through `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested loop with a step (number of sheets) you want to jump.

```vb
For i = 1 To 80 Step 8
    For j = i + 1 To i + 7
        'Write your logic to copy data from sheet (i) into sheets (j)
    Next
Next
```